# NSViewController performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to understand how does performSegueWithIdentifier work. I do some google, read the posts here, follow some YouTube video but it didn't work as per the video. Am I missing anything?

I setup a very simple test

1) ViewController.swift and SecondViewController.swift

2) Ctrl drag from ViewController view to SecondViewController view and choose Modal

3) Add a Text box and Go button on the ViewController view and variables setup at ViewController.swift

4) Add a Label to display to display the data passing from ViewController

Problems:

1) The second view controller never fire up??

2) When debug, it look like the performSegueWithIdentifier did not activated as I put a print command inside the performSegueWithIdentifier function to print out something to ensure it has been called but nothing printed

What did I missed???

Below is my ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txt_val: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func btnConfirm(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondViewController", sender: txt_val.stringValue)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("Called \(segue)") // Nothing print out here when btnConfirm was clicked
        if segue.identifier == "SecondViewController"{
            let vc = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController
            vc.viaSegue = txt_val.stringValue
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my SecondViewController.swift code:

```
import Cocoa

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dsp_label: NSTextField!
    var viaSegue:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        dsp_label.stringValue = viaSegue
        print("viaSegue: \(viaSegue)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you linked the button to the `btnConfirm` method in the Storyboard? Also change the sender arg in `performSegueWithIdentifier` to `self` or `sender`

Comment: Yes, I did Ctrl + Drag the btnConfirm to ViewController.swift so it created the `IBAction func btnConfirm`. I try to change the performSequeWithIndentifier as per your suggestion to either self or sender `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondViewController", sender: self)` or `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondViewController", sender: sender)` but it still not working

Comment: Have you set the identifier of the segue in Interface Builder to `SecondViewController` ?

Comment: I finally found the problem. The problem is actually due to the Identifier. Previously I set the identifier under the View. The correct way should be first click on the Segue link (a line linked between two ViewController) then click on the Attributes Inspector. Set the identifier here and solve the problem.